# Node.js high-level servers' communication API

Tags: node.js

folks. I wander whether there is any high-level API for servers' communication in Node.js framework? For example, I have several servers, where my application runs and I want to control loading of this servers. Sometimes, if some server is overloaded I want to redirect some connection requests to another(more free one). Are there any functions which could help me? Or I have to implement my own functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [cluster](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/). This allows you to control multiple node proccess and scale nicely.

Alternatively just set up TCP sockets and pass messages around over TCP or pass messages around over a database like redis.

You should be able to pipe HTTP connection down streams. You have one HTTP server as a load balancer and this server just passes messages on to your other servers and passes them back.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for what's called a *load balancer*.  There are many off-the-shelf solutions, [nginx](http://nginx.net) being one of the standards today (and VERY quick/easy to set up).

I don't know of a node-native solution, but it's not that hard to write one.  In general, however, load balancers don't actually monitor server load, they monitor whether a server is live or not and distribute traffic relatively equally.

As for your communications question, no -- there's no standardized API to communicate to/from node.js servers.  Again, however, not hard to set up -- Assuming you're already hosting HTTP (using express, or native), just listen for specific requests, perhaps to `/comm/` or whatever you deem appropriate and pass JSON back-and-forth.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure for Nodejs but I've heard ppl using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) with Nodejs